# Error Compiling libgta 1.0.8 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, makefile, compilation

Hi I tried to compile libgta 1.0.8 on ubuntu 16.04 
this happened : (on terminal )

```
john@john-K53SV:~/gta/libgta$ sudo make 
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/john/gta/libgta'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/john/gta/libgta/doc'
doxygen doxyfile
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/john/gta/libgta/doc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/john/gta/libgta/doc'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/john/gta/libgta/doc'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/john/gta/libgta/src'
  CC       gta.lo
  CCLD     libgta.la
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libbz2.a(bzlib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S 
against `BZ2_crc32Table' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libbz2.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:441: recipe for target 'libgta.la' failed
make[2]: *** [libgta.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/john/gta/libgta/src'
Makefile:491: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/john/gta/libgta'
Makefile:400: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have added `-fPIC` flag to Makefile (`CFLAGS = -g -O2 -fPIC`) and it still not working!

Please help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libbz2.a(bzlib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S \
against `BZ2_crc32Table' can not be used when making a shared object; \
recompile with -fPIC
```

This linker diagnostic is telling you that it cannot use the object file `bzlib.o`
which is a member of the static library `/usr/local/lib/libbz2.a` to build
a shared library (which you are trying to do) because any object file that
can be linked in a shared library must have been compiled with Position-Independent Code; and it is advising you to recompile `bzlib.o` with the `fPIC`
option to achieve that. (And then you would need to recreate the static library `libbz2.a`
to contain the newly built `bzlib.o`).

Setting your `CFLAGS = -g -O2 -fPIC` will not help because that only
affects the object files you are compiling; not the already compiled object files
you are merely linking from `libbz2.a`

But you don't need to rebuild `libbz2.a`. You simply need to let the linker find
a shared rather than static version of `libbz2`, i.e. `libbz2.so` rather
than `libbz2.a`.

A shared version of `libbz2` is very likely already installed on your Ubuntu 16.04 system. See
what:

```
$ locate libbz2.so
```

reports. If something like:

```
...
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
...
```

your're good. If by any chance you haven't got one then:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0
```

Having found or installed a shared `libbz2`, delete the static `libbz2.a` that you have in
`/usr/local/lib/` and try your `libgta` build again.

Comment: Thanks ! It helped a lot